# DateTime property value is not correctly received in Asp.Net Core WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

I am using Asp.Net Core 2.2 WebApi and WinForm Client for sending requests. I am using RestSharp library as Restclient. It seems Property values with DateTime type is not correctly handled in WebApi Controller.

Source DateTime:

[image]

Target DateTime:

[image]

Client side code:

```
internal virtual void Add(T1 businessObject)
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(ManagementControllerName + @"/" + AddActionPrefix, Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddJsonBody(businessObject);
    var response = Globals.ServiceStackClient.Execute(request);

    if (!response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        var ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppExceptionMessage>(response.Content);

        throw new ClientSideException(ex);
    };
}
```

Business object:

```
public class DmPresentationBo : CatalogBo
{
    public DmPresentationBo()
    {

    }

    public string DocItemNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime DocItemDt { get; set; }
}
```

WebApi Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Add")]
public ActionResult<T1> Add([FromBody] T1 businessObject)
{
    try
    {
        CurrentDbStorage.StartTransaction();
        var mainCmd = CurrentDbStorage.GenerateCrudInsertCommand(businessObject);
        mainCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ProcessPostAdd(businessObject);
        CurrentDbStorage.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CurrentDbStorage.RollbackTransaction();
        var parsedEx = CurrentExceptionMgr.ParseErrorMsg(ex.Message);
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(parsedEx);
    };

    return Ok(businessObject);
}
```

Setting Breakpoint within controller, it showed me that BusinessObject deserialized incorrectly, like DocItemDt property value is less than actual one which sent by Client. Surfing google, there are some problems with Json DateTime handling, however none of them helped me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What values are you passing to the controller and what values did you receive?  You say *...like DocItemDt property value is less than actual one which sent by Client...* what are these values?

Comment: if you expand `DocItemDt` in the debugger it will tell you if it's local time or UTC. Can you confirm that both dates are local or both are in UTC? If one is local and another is in UTC, then it's fine.

Comment: In my personal computer everything working properly, however problem occurs when I deploy WebApi and WinClient to physical computers. Interesting is that, both of these 2 computers have the same Time Zone: Baku +4:00. Both projects deployed in Remote Desktop.

Comment: The time is out by 4 hours. Your timezone is +4. I suspect that may be related.

Comment: @mjwills I checked time zones on both machines, they are the same.

Comment: I bet they're not both UTC though.  One is UTC, the other is local (Baku +4). Just convert both to UTC.

Comment: As of now, I just adding 5 hours in order to get the same. However, did not understand what is happening despite being in the same TZ. Thanks.